# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'

Tags: python, json, attributes

I wrote little script on python 3.7 to receive actual browser version

Here is it:

```
import json


def json_open():
    file_json = open('/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Test/configuration.json')
    return json.load(file_json)


def get_last_version(browser_name):
    f = json_open()
    res = (f['global']['link_to_latest_browser_version'])
    last_version = repr(res.json()['latest']['client'][browser_name]['version'])
    #print(last_version[1:-1])
    return last_version[1:-1]
```

Also, json file exists, but it does not matter now.

Received:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'.
```

In row

```
last_version = repr(res.json()['latest']['client'][browser_name]['version'])
```

Please, tell me what is my mistake?

Comment: Can you show the JSON file or at least the structure?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to convert `res` as a json object try `json.loads(res)` instead of `res.json()`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import json

FILEJSON = '/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Test/configuration.json'

def get_last_version(browser_name):
    with open(FILEJSON, 'r') as fson:  
        res = json.load(fson)
    last_version = res['global']['link_to_latest_browser_version']\
                    ['latest']['client'][browser_name]['version'][1:-1]
    return last_version
```

I think that the `json_open` function is unnecessary. Also take into account that the behavior of the `json.load()` method depends on the [type of file you are reading.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders)

Comment: I have corrected the answer, there was a typo. I meant `json.load`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem is here:

```
    last_version = repr(res.json()['latest']['client'][browser_name]['version'])
```

A JSON object is basically a dictionary. So when you do `json['key']` it returns the content, not a json object.

Here `res` is a string, not a json object and thus does not have the `.json()` attribute.

**Edit:**
If you want a string to be return in your situation:

```
res = json.loads(f['global']['link_to_latest_browser_version'])
last_version = res['latest']['client'][browser_name]['version']

return last_version
```

Comment: It is idea, I want to receive output exactly in string? Is it possible?

Comment: Just return `res`, it is already a string. Try to print(res) or print(type(res)), you'll see !

Answer (score 0):

Your "res" variable is of type string. 
Strings do not have an attribute called json. 
So res.json() is invalid.

Comment: I want to receive return exactly in str.

Any ideas how perform it?

Comment: Could you be more clear on what exactly it is you want to achieve with res.json()?

Comment: The output should be '83.0.4103.61'. Type str

Comment: What is the value of res ?